# SQL Server 2019 LIKE script with wildcard is not working while MySQL is OK

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2019 with graph tables. My script returns only Id9 while the same script under MySQL returns ID4,8,9 (which is the expected result). I don't know why the '%' used as prefix is not working on SQL Server.

Here's the script:

```
CREATE TABLE Test([Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                    [FullName] nvarchar(128) NULL,

                    CONSTRAINT [PK_Test_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC));

INSERT INTO Test (FullName) VALUES 
(N'F''Sheree Jones II'                 ),
(N'Cybèle'                             ),
(N'T''Junior'                          ),
(N'Urane Of Watson Lake'               ),
(N'J''Sirène De Dan Jourdain'          ),
(N'Goodson des loups de l''antarctique'),
(N'F''Sheree Jones Of Dawson City'     ),
(N'Pénélope Of Watson Lake'            ),
(N'Liubov''s Siren'                    ),
(N'Siréna'                             );

select * from Test where FullName like '%siren%'
```

Comment: What did you expect then?

Comment: What is your database collation? If some _CI_AS variety, then everything is correct.

Comment: I suppose you're looking for `select * from Test where FullName like '%siren%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI` which will returns the IDs 5, 9 and 10.

Comment: @Sami - Your's is the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@NolmëInformatique, this is the variant with table-valued function usage:

```
create function schema_name.function_name (@name nvarchar(100))
returns table
as
return 
(
select FullName from Test 
WHERE FullName COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI Like '%'+@name+'%' 
COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI
);
```

The function can be called via this query:

```
select * from schema_name.function_name ('siren');
```

Comment: @NolmëInformatique, the problem is fixed. I've concatenated variable and '%' signs wrong

Answer (score 2):

Because a letter with accent is not the same letter without one. And you should consider uppercase letters. Try this code:
`select * from Test WHERE upper(FullName) COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI Like '%CAFE%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI`

Comment: OH YES :) (I've changed the %CAFE% by %SIREN%). thanks.

Comment: What's the need of `UPPER()` function while you're using `COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI`?

Comment: @Sami I voted up on your comment by mistake, and I cannot undo it. The collation is highly important. test it :-) The collate is more than the CI part.

Comment: If a collation is Case Insensitve, then the `UPPER` isn't needed, @RonenAriely .

Comment: I "bother" to tell you that you made a mistake @Sami same as you did well when you inform someone else on something you thought he mad not well

Comment: You're just giving a wrong informations to the readers and guide them to wrong direction. That's what your comments is doing in addition to rudeness.

Comment: @Larnu did you tested it? Please do, and remember that his text is not in English. Test these two (1) `select * from Test WHERE upper(FullName) Like '%SIREN%'` and `select * from Test WHERE  upper(FullName) COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI Like '%siren%'  COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI`` ...

Comment: Here is full demo: http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/254/Does-COLLATE-important-when-we-use-the-function-UPPER-on-the-text.aspx

Comment: Yes I mad a mistake (and I have no problem saying it directly in the forum), but is this rude?!? By the way, my mistake was that, I was thinking you speak about the *important of the COLLATE when using UPPER* and you spoke about the *important of the UPPER when using the COLLATE*. After I published my demo, I re-read your comment and notice the mistake.

Comment: @Vad1m : is it possible / interesting to put this request inside a function which will be called with EntityFramework / Linq ?

Comment: @NolmëInformatique It can be put in table-valued function. I've never used EntityFramework / Linq, 
so you should test whether function works in this way.

P.s. I see answer of Sami. It's right one and has been posted a bit earlier than mine.
P.p.s. Latin1_general_CI_AI means case-insensitive and accent-insensitive, 
so using 'upper' function is not obligatory and other users wrote useful comments

Comment: @NolmëInformatique just added another answer with table-valued function. Please check whether it works

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to **@Vad1m's** answer above.
The 'Siren' in your table has a Capitalized 'S'.

Check if server is case insensitive or not. Run this query:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION')
```

If result is:

```
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

`CI` means case insensitive.

If not, you will need to use `lower()` function in your where clause.

Comment: it returns : French_CI_AS

Comment: @NolmëInformatique The results you're getting because of the `AS`.